# Looking for a java library that has implemented Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Is there a java library that has Binary Tree that I can use? I am not looking forward to test and implement my own.

Comment: What do you need the binary tree for?

Comment: Basically the java.util.TreeSet is a red-black binary tree, which is a balanced binary search tree. Depends on what you need, though.

Comment: Yeah - the binary tree I would like to store need not be balanced. Besides, it is not a binary search tree. I am looking for the basic implementation where every node has a left and right child.

Comment: As per your last comment, in java there is a linked list which has left and child node for every node.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Java standard API only contains libraries that are universally useful and non-trivial to implement. A basic tree is trivial to implement:

```
class BinaryTree {
    BinaryTree left;
    BinaryTree right;
    Object value;
}
```

Non-trivial trees are not universally useful: either they are needed as a part of the application data model, which is better modeled using domain specific classes (component has-a list of sub-components), or they are used as a part of a specific algorithm. Algorithms usually require a specific structure from the nodes (e.g. the color or weight of the node needed to maintain the tree balanced), so a generic tree node makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks @Joni - that makes sense. I guess I took it for granted that it must be there - but it is not. I will implement it for my app.

Comment: You are right with the basic tree, but there are definitely parts of a non-trivial BST implementation that are as universally useful as anything, like finding lowest and inserting/removing (and balancing), don't you think?

Comment: Finding highest/lowest in a BST could be done, but I don't see how you could do a general insertion or removal that would work for all tree types. Also note that the question was about *general binary trees*, with no guarantees or requirements on ordering, and not about BSTs.

Answer (score 12):

What about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural
>   ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

Comment: It would not work for me. I am looking for a basic Binary Tree.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Swing's [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) and its implementation - [DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html).

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53366/Binary-Trees-in-Java

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/BinaryTree.htm

Comment: No - I would like to import it and say : BinaryTree x =new BinaryTree(); in another words, I would like to reuse a working package, class ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample implementation on this page here: -around at the bottom half of the page or so-

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html

Comment: I am looking for a tested library.

Comment: @Esey, then write the tests yourself...

Comment: @Bart - May be another time :) - I could implement it myself too - but I am implementing an app that  "uses" Binary Trees and would be nice if I did not have to worry about this other piece. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Esey, you're *really* looking for a BT (binary tree), and not a BST (binary search tree)? With a BT, there is no order between the values in the tree. A bit odd to have need for such a tree...