# Create an array with the keys of nodes

Tags: java, arrays, tree, binary-tree, heapsort

I currently have a binary tree setup and would like to create an array with the keys so I can do a heap sort operation on them. How would I go about doing that?

Here is what I currently have:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("employee.txt"));
    String line;
    Heap employee = new Heap();

    while((line = in.readLine())!= null)
    {
        String[]text = line.split(" ");
        employee.insert(Double.parseDouble(text[0]), Double.parseDouble(text[1]));

    }
    in.close();
}
```

The binary tree that I am using is pretty standard but I can post it if needed. The "text[0]" segment is what the key is for each node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet--) class in combination with a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). The TreeSet can behave like a heap. The class is well documented, but if you have more questions, ask.

EDIT

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900454/looking-for-a-java-library-that-has-implemented-binary-tree). The accepted answer shows you an implementation of a binary tree. What you need now is a sorting function implementation in that class, which may be triggered at element insertion or manually when needed.

I still don't see how you want to switch a tree into a heap as they are different things. I guess you mean the tree should be "read" say from left to right and so rearranged?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can use that. We're supposed to use a binary tree so I'm trying to figure out how to create a array based on the key themselves.

Comment: A binary tree you'll have to implement yourself. You need to specify what are the keys you're using, if you want more assistance. Or you can think about using a ready Map implementation.

Comment: I already have the binary tree created. The key's that I'm using is the "text[0]" within the insert function. Currently it is reading from a text file and the first number on the line is the key and the second one is that data.